# OR and AND operators not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, cookies

A user can set any one cookie on their browser. One that will be set if the submits the their email for subscription and another if they don't want to see the pop up again.

```
@if(Cookie::get("english")!=1 and Cookie::get("stop_popup")!=1)
//my html code here
@endif
```

The user should see the subscription popup if they don't have both cookie above. They should not see the subscription box if they have `english` or `stop_popup` cookie set in their device.

```
@if(Cookie::get("english")!=1)
@endif
```

Only single condition works not both. Why is that? Have I done anything wrong in the above code?

Comment: Try change ```and``` to ```&&```

Comment: "if they have english or stop_popup" I think you might want to change and to or. Cookie::get('english') or Cookie::get('stop_popup')

Comment: do you actually care about this value you are checking, or only if they have the cookies at all?

Comment: @lagbox I want to check if the cookie with the above name exists or not

Comment: dd(Cookie::get("english")); both

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cookie::has(...)` to see if the cookies exists at all as an alternative:

```
@if (! Cookie::has('english') && ! Cookie::has('stop_popup'))
```

If the 'english' cookie does not exist and the 'stop_popup' cookie does not exist.

Comment: The popup should show if both cookie is not set. But if anyone is set then the popup should not display.

Comment: which is what that says ... if there isn't a cookie named 'english' and there isn't a cookie named 'stop_popup' .... if either or both of them exist the condition would not pass

Comment: then one of those cookies is being sent with the request

Comment: how can you make what work? it sounds like it works, are you checking to see what cookies are set in your browser that you are sending with each request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223138/discussion-between-gaurav-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
@if (empty(Cookie::get("english")) && empty(Cookie::get("stop_popup")))
    // html code here
@endif
```